# Vuejs - How to Increase the security in Vuejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, express, vue.js

I have build a WebApp which uses Vue and Retrieve Data using 'vue-resource' from Backend (Express + Postgres)

And I want to Improve it's security by Adding API Key.

I am bit confused is API Key is added as a variable on both the sides and if possible how to send it from vue-resource and get it on other end and authenticate?

Comment: I think this question is better to search online rather than to ask on here.

Comment: If you want better answers you need to be descriptive with your problem, and precise with what you need an answer to.

Comment: Question is now more descriptive 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an API that talks to your Database, then the webapp talks to your API.

- use JWT or Basic Auth between your app and this API
- use the postgres credentials between the API and your database
- create routes for the queries you'd like to run

  - /users/all = `select * from users`
  - /users/123 = `select * from users where id = 123`

This is a simple way to guarantee security.

---

Bonus points if you

- dont use `postgres` as your credentials but create your own
- only allow the IP of your API connection to your DB, and not a public IP.
- use prepared statements to avoid accidental SQL injection and syntax mistakes

Comment: Thanks A lot. Actually I'm rookie but it helped me now I'm using JWT and tokens while logging in and I also enabled express-limitter.